# How do I finish this proof that $f(z)=z/(1-|z| )$ is onto?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is my start:

$f$ is the function from the open unit disc to R2

$f(z)$ is onto since for every $w$ in the codomain, there exists a $z$ such that $f(z)=w.$ Hence $w=\dfrac{z} {(1-|z|)}$, so by taking moduli:

$$|w|=|z|/(1-|z| )$$
$$|w|(1-|z| )=|z|$$
$$|w|-|z||w|=|z|$$
$$|w|=|z|+|z||w|$$
$$|w|=|z|(1+|w|)$$
$$|z|=|w|/(1+|w|)$$

Now where do I go?
Thanks, FGH.

Comment: You need to give the domain and the codomain; it's part of the definition of $f$.

Comment: If you don't give the question some context, it will be hard for you to get an answer.

Comment: One last line to conclude the proof: *Thus $1-|z|=1/(1+|w|)$ and $z=w(1-|z|)=w/(1+|w|)$. QED.*

Comment: Sorry! The domain is the unit disk and the co-domain is R2.

Comment: Does my indication allow you to finish the proof?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much @Didier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm retaining as much as possible from your own wording; but note the differences!

The function $f(z):={z\over 1-|z|}$ is a function from the open unit disc $D$ to ${\mathbb C}$.

The function $f$ is onto **if** (not: "since") for every $w$ in the codomain ${\mathbb C}$, there exists a $z\in D$ such that $f(z)=w\ $, i.e., $${z\over 1-|z|}=w\ .\qquad(1)$$ So by taking moduli:
$$|w|={|z|\over 1-|z| }$$
or
$$|z|={|w|\over 1+|w|}\ .\qquad(2)$$
On the other hand, taking arguments in $(1)$ for a $z$ with $|z|<1$ we get
$$\arg(z)=\arg(w)\ .\qquad(3)$$
Equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ together imply that a $z$ of the required kind would necessarily be given by 
$$z:={w\over 1+|w|}\ .$$
Now we have arrived at this result not by means of a general theory about such problems, but by means of an ad-hoc procedure. Therefore we have to check whether the $z$ we have found indeed fulfills the conditions $z\in D$ and $f(z)=w$. I leave this verification to you.